# Using exported (From Workspace Block) Signal in Simulink as input signal to a filter

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, simulink

I have generated some **ECG Signals** in MATLAB workspace and then exported the signal data in the Simulink using the from **Workspace Block**. Now, I want to use the exported signal as an input signal to a filter network. How can I use this exported data as input signal. I am attaching the Simulink model diagram for better understanding. [Simulink Block Diagram of the System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Gcg.png)

I have tried connecting the output of the **From Workspace** block to input it in the filter network. I have also tried it using **From File** block to do the same. But I end up at the same point at not connecting the output to any of the point in my filter network.

Comment: better ask this at DSP